# How do you insert info that is on one table to another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: `TheOfficer` & `TheStage` and both have `Zipcode` and `stageID` columns. Unfortunately for some of the data `Zipcode` is missing on the `TheStage` table.

But the data can be on `TheOfficer` table. I would like to copy the `Zipcode` found on `TheOfficer` table to the `Zipcode` column on `TheStage` table.

Something like:

```
Insert into TheStage (TheStage.Zipcode)
from TheOfficer 
where TheOfficer.stageID = TheStage.stageID
```

Comment: you have to `update` in that case..not `insert`.

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for an UPDATE and not INSERT? Whoops... @vkp beat me to it.

Comment: Are rows with certain zipcodes missing as well from TheStage table or just some info on stageID?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that stageID links the two tables:

```
UPDATE TheStage(Zipcode)
   SET Zipcode = (SELECT Zipcode
                    FROM TheOfficer
                   WHERE TheStage.stageID = TheOfficer.stageID)
```

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
Update TheStage
Set TheStage.Zipcode = TheOfficer.Zipcode
from TheOfficer
where TheStage.stageID = TheOfficer.stageID
```